# Java POI SS issue with Excel Outline and Expand/Collapse

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm running into an issue with Excel Outlining using POI SS. I create
three groups with "Test1" being the root node. I collapse each group as well
using setRowGroupCollapsed. However, when I expand the first node on the
Excel File generated, all the other nodes are also expanded.

Is there a setting to prevent this? I would like to have all levels collapsed and if I expand the first level, the lower levels should remain collapsed until I
expand them.

Below is my test code and any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance,

```
sheet.setAlternativeExpression(false);    
sheet.setRowSumsBelow(false);

Row excelRow = null;    
Cell excelCell = null;

excelRow = sheet.createRow( 0 );    
excelCell = excelRow.createCell( 0 );    
excelCell.setCellValue( "Test 1" );

excelRow = sheet.createRow( 1 );    
excelCell = excelRow.createCell( 1 );    
excelCell.setCellValue( "Test 2" );    

excelRow = sheet.createRow( 2 );    
excelCell = excelRow.createCell( 2 );    
excelCell.setCellValue( "Test 3" );


excelRow = sheet.createRow( 3 );    
excelCell = excelRow.createCell( 3 );    
excelCell.setCellValue( "Test 4" );

sheet.groupRow( 1, 3 );    
sheet.groupRow( 2, 3 );    
sheet.groupRow( 3, 3 );    

sheet.setRowGroupCollapsed( 1, true );    
sheet.setRowGroupCollapsed( 2, true );    
sheet.setRowGroupCollapsed( 3, true );
```